# Button turns blue on press (not outline, not select highlight)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that turn blue when the user holds on to it for a while sample below on mobile. Sample below

[image]

This not an issue with `::selected` or outline has i have added that and it didn't work.

The whole button turns blue for a few seconds and disappears. How do i stop the button from turning blue?

Comment: I really don't understand how this needs a code @SaymoinSam but ill edit now.

Comment: Pls help people help you by providing a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That blue tone looks like the blue with which chrome highlights the parts you select with the DevTools

Comment: Have a look at [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), especially [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could infer from your problem statement, the `background-color` of your button might be changing due to `:active` pseudo-class acting on it which stays for few seconds of click on button and then when click is released it disappears. You may target the `button:active` selector and override the behavior with the desired `background-color` and `color`. I have tried creating a mock of what may help you.

```css
button{
background-color: blue;
color: #ffffff;
height: 32px;
}
/* scenario you might need to override with the background color you want to retain */
button:active{
background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">Trial</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please post your code. Another way we cant help you. we dont know the problem. why button is looks like that. You are telling us about the problem but didn't show anything about problem